# nHibernate Expression.In throwing an Exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this nHibernate Critera which works fine

```
var amount = (decimal)Session.CreateCriteria<Transaction>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Account.Id", accountId))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Account.Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("InvoiceGross"), "total"))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
    .UniqueResult<IDictionary>()["total"];
```

but when I start to add `Expression.In` like this

```
var amount = (decimal)Session.CreateCriteria<Transaction>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Account.Id", accountId))
    .Add(Expression.In("StatusType.Id", statusTypes))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Account.Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("InvoiceGross"), "total"))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
    .UniqueResult<IDictionary>()["total"];
```

Any ideas why is it happening, by the way **`statusTypes`** is an **`int[]`** type

it starts to throw an exception `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

This is the SQL Query I want to achieve

```
SELECT SUM(InvoiceGross) AS total
FROM  Transactions
WHERE (AccountID = @accountId) (statusTypeID IN (1,2,3,4))
GROUP BY AccountID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error ie being thrown cos you are not getting an unique result from the database. Can you monitor the generated sql using SQL profiler or NHProf and then run that against the db to see  if the query is indeed returning data.

Also before you start using the ResultTransformer just cast it to a simple List and see if you are getting an array list with the Account.Id as the first item of the array and the sum is the second item i.e try

```
var amount = (decimal)Session.CreateCriteria<Transaction>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("Account.Id", accountId))
    .Add(Expression.In("StatusType.Id", statusTypes))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Account.Id"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("InvoiceGross"), "total"))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .List();

var sum=amount[0][1];
```

Comment: Yup I got where I am having an exception, this gave me the idea where my error came from, the UniqueResult is giving me the issue as I am returning a null data.  +1